# Optimizing the search in 10 columns and applying it in Spring Boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

In my traffic app, there is a database table with information about tram stops. To each tram stop it can be assigned up to 11 strings (each in separate column) which describes the direction from which the trams leave from a platform.

The query below illustrates a situation when a user types in the name of the tram stop and the direction, so that a specific platform is choosen. The query deals with users putting lowercase / only latin characters so that `ĄŚĆ` is also found for `asc` input.

```
SELECT id
FROM  stations_directions
WHERE 
((offline IS NULL) OR (offline <> 1)) 
AND 
(name = ?1) 
AND 
(
translate(lower(main_dir), 'ąćęłńóśźż', 'acelnoszz') = ?2 
OR 
translate(lower(add_dir1), 'ąćęłńóśźż', 'acelnoszz') = ?2 
OR 
translate(lower(add_dir2), 'ąćęłńóśźż', 'acelnoszz') = ?2 
OR 
translate(lower(add_dir3), 'ąćęłńóśźż', 'acelnoszz') = ?2 
OR 
translate(lower(add_dir4), 'ąćęłńóśźż', 'acelnoszz') = ?2 
OR 
translate(lower(add_dir5), 'ąćęłńóśźż', 'acelnoszz') = ?2 
OR 
translate(lower(add_dir6), 'ąćęłńóśźż', 'acelnoszz') = ?2 
OR 
translate(lower(add_dir7), 'ąćęłńóśźż', 'acelnoszz') = ?2 
OR 
translate(lower(add_dir8), 'ąćęłńóśźż', 'acelnoszz') = ?2 
OR 
translate(lower(add_dir9), 'ąćęłńóśźż', 'acelnoszz') = ?2    
OR 
translate(lower(add_dir10), 'ąćęłńóśźż', 'acelnoszz') = ?2
)
```

As you can see the query is long and repetitive. Im looking for ways how to optimize it either by altering the query or the database.

Another question is how to use such a query in Spring Boot JPA? With JPQL there is no possibility to use methods as `lower()`. I tried with `EntityManager` and `createNativeQuery()` but it did not work out:

```
EntityManager em;
public String findId(String name, String direction, String sql) {
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
    q.setParameter(1,name);
    q.setParameter(2,direction);
    return q.getSingleResult().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use instead:

```
create extension unaccent;
create table stations (
  station_id serial primary key,
  name text not null,
  offline boolean not null
);
create table station_directions (
  station_id int not null references stations(station_id),
  direction text not null,
  primary_key(station_id, direction)
);
```

And a query:

```
select station_id from stations
join station_directions using station_id
where
  name=?
  and not offline
  and lower(unaccent(direction))=?;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I might have forgot to add how the table is created. As there are over 600 platforms, with 11 directions for each one, that makes over 6600 directions combinations. They have to be put manually for each platform. To make this job faster, it's done in excel, [see image](http://oi68.tinypic.com/2vjygx5.jpg) then the table is exported to SQL. Do you have an idea how to modify the excel table so that the sql relations can be made?

Comment: Also if I understand correclty, this model is a 1-to-many relationship. What I need is however a many-to-many relationship, as there can be many platforms in a city that lead in one direction (e.g. "downtown") and at the same time one platform can lead to many directions.